# Spring MVC Custom Authentication Issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

My application produces a 404 Error page (resource not found) when attempting to login. I've setup all my authentication classes properly. The link it forwards to is: `http://localhost:23121/IssueTracking/j_spring_security_check`

Heres my code below:

**login.jsp**

```html
<form action='<c:url value="/j_spring_security_check"/>' method='post'>
    <fieldset>   
        <input name="j_username" id="j_username"  type="text" class="span12" placeholder="Username" />
        <input  name="j_password" id="j_password" type="password" class="span12" placeholder="Password" />
        <button type="submit" class="width-35 pull-right btn btn-small btn-primary">Login</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**web.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="3.1" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
   <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
   </listener>
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   <session-config>
      <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
   </session-config>
   <!-- Spring Security -->
   <filter>
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
   </filter>
   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
   <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
   </listener>
   <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/issuetracking-security.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>
</web-app>
```

**issuetracking-security.xml (Security xml config file)**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd">
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <form-login login-page="/login.jsp"
            always-use-default-target="true" authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?error=true"
             authentication-success-handler-ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler" 
            default-target-url="/" />

        <intercept-url pattern="/*" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/myTickets" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER')" />
                <intercept-url pattern="/ticketList" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/index.jsp" />
    </http>
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="loginService"/>
    </authentication-manager>
    <beans:bean id="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler" 
         class="net.fluidinnovations.security.CustomAuthenticationSessionHandler">
        <beans:property name="roleUrlMap">
            <beans:map>
                <beans:entry key="ROLE_USER" value="/myTickets"/>
                <beans:entry key="ROLE_ADMIN" value="/ticketList"/>
            </beans:map>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: I have added language tags to your code so that it gets correctly coloured. It would be helpful if you could post your `CustomAuthenticationSessionHandler` implementation. We need to know exactly how your application works to try and debug anything. You say you've set up your authentication classes correctly, but there might be something subtle that you've missed, and we can't fix it if we can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

You have two `ContextLoaderListener` declarations, remove the one at the bottom

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/issuetracking-security.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And change the one at the top to;

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml, /WEB-INF/issuetracking-security.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
     <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

And I don't see a `contextConfigLocation` for your `DispatcherServlet` so I assume you create the Web MVC related beans in your `applicationContext.xml`. But if you don't you need to set that.